# How to create an input template/preset for a custom pine script strategy?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible hard code input templates into my pine script strategy?

I need to switch between input presets like this: e.g. The built in Trend Line Tool allows you to save and load input templates (Template1, Template2, Trendline):

[image: Input template example]

I wasn't able to find anything about this in the documentation.

But I'd like to be able to hard code (or even just save) my own input templates, then switch between them at run time and tweak the values.

---

**What I have already tried**

Creating a drop down, then using the selection in if statements to:

1. Update the variables which I use as the defVal for my inputs. [**Fail:** defVal only accepts const variables]

```
// Defaults
defaultInput1 = 1

If (template1)
    defaultInput1 := 999
    
If (template2)
    defaultInput1 := 123

// Throws exception, defaultInput1 must be const
Input1 = input(defVal=defaultInput1, ...)
```

2. Create seperate sets of duplicate inputs inside if statements. [**Sort of fail:** I hoped that only the selected inputs would be rendered, but it turns out they're all rendered at once. It works and I can edit the values, but I end up with a lot of duplicated inputs to scroll through).

```
// Defaults
Input1 = 0
Input2 = 0

If (template1)
    Input1 := input(defVal=1, ...)
    Input2 := input(defVal=2, ...)

If (template2)
    Input1 := input(defVal=500, ...)
    Input2 := input(defVal=123, ...)
        
// ^ Ends up displaying all of the inputs on screen, regardless of which drop down option is selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

indicators don't have templates only drawings have

Comment: Seeing that the existing answer already implies "not possible" (by only proposing a workaround), what is the additional insight your post contributes?

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Girish Kuvalekar .

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for option 1
Try using a bool like

```
    temp = input(type = input.bool, text = "Use template 1", defval = true)

int default_input = na //declaring a global variable
if(temp == true)
    default_input := 999
else
    default_input := 123
```

or if you have multiple options to select from use this

```
check = (Title = "Select one", defval = "Template1", options["Template1","template2","template3"]

//and then use above method with nested ifs or if and elseif
```

Workaround for option 2
What I think the mistake is that you are giving it space to fulfil both conditions, change it to be something like this:

```
// Defaults
Input1 = 0
Input2 = 0

If (template1)
    Input1 := input(defVal=1, ...)
    Input2 := input(defVal=2, ...)

If (template2 == true and template1 == false)  //if(template2 and ! template1) will also work just fine
    Input1 := input(defVal=500, ...)
    Input2 := input(defVal=123, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both of them out just now, but unfortunately they don't work. Option 1 still results in a non-const variable. And option 2 also produces the same result my original question.